# pandas, matplolib, how do I plot diagram with empty position for recent 30 days, when I dont have recent few days data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe for a client that closed in recent weeks, the dataframe should be like this:

```
date         sales
2020-06-25   1221
2020-06-21   1333
2020-06-20   553
2020-06-19   111
```

If we choose the last day of June (June 30) to plot the monthly report, and the report does not have any records for dates from `2020-06-26` to `2020-06-30`, the chart won't show the last few days, but client wants to see empty records instead. How to do that?

In the example below, today is July 17, we expect to see July 15-17 as empty:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose these dates are not in your dataframe, because if they were, you will have empty records as you want. So you will just need to create rows with the dates you want to be added. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='7/1/2020', end='7/15/2020'),'sales':[a for a in range(15)]})
#This line adds dates 16 and 17 july
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start='7/16/2020', end='7/17/2020')}),ignore_index=True)
df.plot.bar(x='Date',y='sales')
```